# rsync temporary failure in name resolution when tried to use rsyncd

Tags: domain-name-system, rsync, resolve

I tried to use `rsyncd` to transfer projects from client to server (push operation). `rsync` (`3.1.2`) are installed and running on both client and server, with the server running `rsyncd`. The `rsyncd.conf` is as follows,

```
pid file = /run/rsyncd.pid
strict mode = false

log file = /var/log/rsync.log

[dir1]
comment = test folder dir1
path = /opt/dir1/
uid = user_name
gid = group_name
read_only = false
```

when I tried the following command,

```
rsync -aurv /path/to/dir1/ user@host_name::dir1
```

I got the following errors,

```
rsync: getaddrinfo: host_name 873: Temporary failure in name resolution
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [sender=3.1.2]
```

The client and the destination server are connected through a bastion server. There is no issue if I just tried,

```
rsync -aurv /path/to/dir1/ user@host_name:/path/to/dir1
```

I am wondering how to fix the errors.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your failure is that the DNS lookup for `host_name` is failing, which is what the error tells you:

```
getaddrinfo: ... failure in name resolution
```

To fix this you could update your command to use the IP address instead, either:

```
rsync -aurv /path/to/dir1/ user@1.2.3.4::dir1
```

or for IPv6:

```
rsync -aurv /path/to/dir1/ user@[fe80::1]::dir1
```

Failing that you could add an entry to `/etc/hosts` to allow the name to resolve - or otherwise fix your DNS problems.

Comment: Hi, since we have a bastion server in between client and the destination server, so I defined an `ssh` port forwarding in `.ssh/config`. Since `rsync` is using `ssh` by default, and in `/etc/hosts`, I defined the external IP only for the bastion server. So I think using `rsyncd.conf` or normal `rsync` makes no difference.

Comment: only the bastion server has external IP, the destination server only has internal IP, so how to specify the IP here in the command?

Comment: Sounds like the simplest solution is to use `rsync` with SSH as the transport - ssh already knows how to reach your host via `~/.ssh/config`.  So use `rsync -e ssh ...` and drop the use of `::`, just using a single colon.

Comment: I found single colon works as well, and so it makes `rsyncd.conf` no use then? or `rsyncd` is not working in `ssh` port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ssh for your rsync transport, you aren't using rsyncd to terminate the remote connection (which is the reference to TCP 873). Otoh if you are simply using a separate ssh tunnel to forward TCP 873 through to the rsyncd server on the inside, then your rsync client is actually going to connect to localhost and ssh will forward.

The double colon syntax is specifying the native rsync protocol (or rsync://). Without that, it will use the rsh/ssh transport method.